# Nested NgbModal issue on dismiss / close

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use a confirmation NgbModal into an already living NgbModal used as a form to modify a user informations.
I'm facing an issue while trying to close or dismiss the confirmation modal: the confirmation modal actually require to be closed / dismissed twice instead of once.

The only thing that could lead to this for me would be that the confirmation modal was opened twice, but i don't understand from where this behaviour would comes...

#### function that calls the form modale

```
public showUserUpdateModale(user: User): void {
    let modalRef1: NgbModalRef;
    modalRef1 = this.modalService.open(UpdateUsersComponent);
    modalRef1.componentInstance.user = user;
    modalRef1.result.then((newUser: User): void => {
      this.userBusiness.updateUser(newUser)
        .then((res: any) => {
          this.toastr.success(`Les informations de l\'utilisateur ${user.firstname} ${user.lastname} ont été prises en compte.`, 'Modification réussie');
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          this.toastr.error('Erreur interne', 'Erreur');
        });
    }).catch((err1: any): void => {
      this.toastr.info('Aucune modification n\'a été enregistrée.');
    });
  }
```

#### update-user.component.ts (form modale)

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/user';
import { ConfirmComponent } from '../confirm';
import { ModalService } from '../../../services/modal.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'update-user',
    templateUrl: './update-user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./update-user.component.scss']
})
export class UpdateUsersComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() public user: User;
    public newUser: User;

    private activeModal: NgbActiveModal;
    private modalService: ModalService;

    constructor(activeModal: NgbActiveModal, modalService: ModalService) {
        this.activeModal = activeModal;
        this.modalService = modalService;
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.newUser = Object.assign({}, this.user);
    }

    public dismiss(): void {
        this.activeModal.dismiss(false);
    }

    public send(): void {
        let modalRef2: NgbModalRef;
        modalRef2 = this.modalService.open(ConfirmComponent);
        modalRef2.componentInstance.message = `<p>Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir valider les modifications apportées à l\'utilisateur ${this.user.firstname} ${this.user.lastname} ?</p>`;
        modalRef2.componentInstance.title = 'Confirmer les modifications';
        modalRef2.result.then((data: any): void => {
            this.activeModal.close(this.newUser);
        })
        .catch((err2: any) => {
            console.log('test');
        });
    }
}
```

#### confirm.component.ts (confirm modale)

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'confirm',
    templateUrl: './confirm.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./confirm.component.scss']
})
export class ConfirmComponent {

    @Input() public title: string;
    @Input() public message: string;

    private activeModal: NgbActiveModal;

    constructor(activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
        this.activeModal = activeModal;
    }

    public dismiss(): void {
        this.activeModal.dismiss(false);
    }

    public send(): void {
        this.activeModal.close(true);
    }
}
```

#### modal.service.ts

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

    private ngbModal: NgbModal;

    constructor(
        ngbModal: NgbModal
    ) {
        this.ngbModal = ngbModal;
    }

    public open(content, options = {}) {
        return this.ngbModal.open(content, { size: 'lg', backdrop: true, centered: true, ...options });
    }
}
```

Comment: minor - there is no `e` in `modal`

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

This looks be caused by your constructors.

In each class' constructor, you are setting the active modal;

`this.activeModal = activeModal;`

and each of your close methods reference the active modal.

So, each of your class' have their own instance of `activeModal`, yet your code to close isn't able to know which one.

```
 modalRef2.result.then((data: any): void => {
            this.activeModal.close(this.newUser);
        })
```

You will need to reference the correct modal to close at the correct time.

Something like:

```
 modalRef2.result.then((data: any): void => {
            modalRef2.close(this.newUser);
        })
```

Comment: Hello Steven, thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. Moreover, the original code is meaningfully correct because i'm calling the confirmation modal, and if it closes successfuly (so its own activeModal is already closed back to the first modal) i would like to close the first modal (because the confirmation has been validated)

Comment: you need to reference the correct modal reference one way or another, this was just an example. I expect a larger code refactor will be required to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could not help me on that because the part of the code that was failing was in .html of the update modale.
I was calling twice the function send() because I had a button type "submit" with a (click)="send()" AND it was in a form that already had a (ngSubmit)="send()".

```
<form (ngSubmit)="send()" #loginForm="ngForm">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <!-- code -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- code -->        
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- code -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-primary-light-blue" type="submit" (click)="send()">Valider la modification</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My fault then, thanks for the answers !

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-template #showImage let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
        // ... 
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

in your button from where your want to close the modal use `(click)="d('Cross click');"`

That will help.